# How does TypedArray methods conversion work

Tags: javascript, binary, typed-arrays

ECMAScript defines a bunch of similar methods: [toInt8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint8), [toInt16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint16), etc.

1) Is my understanding correct that these are used to convert a number in **floating point format** of 64 bits into **two's complement** form of the number of bits corresponding to a method?

2) The gist of the conversion is this step `Let int8bit be int modulo 2^8.` Can anyone clarify why the `modulo` operation is used to convert from `64` bit to `8` bit and how it's actually accomplished on the bit level?

Comment: They are stored as actual binary integers in the width (or rather *type* in this context) they are converted to in an actual byte-array. See f.ex. [ArrayBuffer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraybuffer-constructor).

Comment: @K3N, thanks, _as actual binary integers_ - in a two's complement form? Just noticed [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects) in the description: `8-bit 2’s complement signed integer`. So it seems it converts them to two's complement

Comment: Sorry forgot, but yes as you note, for the signed types always 2s compl. (excluding any older computers :) ). And of course as you know, on top of that byte-order depending on the native CPU it's running on.

Comment: @K3N, yes, thanks. As I understand the gist of the conversion is in this operation `Let int8bit be int modulo 28.`. Do you know how and why is it performed with regard to bits?

Comment: I believe there is partly a historic reason to this. A "byte" didn't necessarily have to be 8-bits in the past. And in some languages there is f.ex. short, but short can be 16-bit on a 32-bit architecture but can be 32-bit wide on a 64-bit arch. etc.. Using bits instead leaves no doubt as to what registry width is intended.

Comment: @K3N, sorry, I must've not made my question clear. I'm interesting in why the conversion is done using `modulo` operation and how this `modulo` operation is performed with bits. Maybe I should create another question or edit this one

Comment: Ah, I see. It doesn't use bits per-se, but using 2^8 for documentation leaves no doubt as to what value is used as well as intention as a byte is formed by 2^8 or 256 values, ie. [0,255] - in code though it will simply use the fixed value representation 256 for modulo (for byte, or it could do f.ex 2^8-1 = 0xff as AND-mask for unsigned values), this of course to guarantee the in-value to fit within the intended registry width (ie. value 256 becomes 0, 257 becomes 1 etc. in the case of byte). The exception is the *ClampedArray which instead of modulo uses clamping (256 becomes 255 etc.).

Comment: Comment field too short though :)

Comment: @K3N, thanks a lot for you insights. I've rephrased the question to make it more generic. We've figured out the first question. Now you can post an answer to the second. You'll have plenty of space to type. Really appreciate! :)